# Yum Error in Cent OS 7 Server

Tags: centos-7, hadoop

I am running into the following error when using yum.

```
yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo, line: 1
'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">\n'
```

I checked the `etc/yum.repos.d/` directory and there is no file in the directory.

How do I resolve this error?

PS: ran into the error while adding repositories for HDP

I tried running yum install ambari server and got the error

Answer (score 0):

Run `grep -irl ambari.repo /etc/` and `find /etc -name ambari.repo`

This will give you exact location of that file. Later you can check and edit the file accordingly.